# How to configure Google Alerts for different languages?

Tags: google-alerts

How can I configure Google Alerts to send me alerts in different languages?

At the moment it alerts me for a certain term only in Italian, that is my default language.
But now I would like to configure the same alert but that returns also English results.

How can I do it?

Comment: Apparently setting up an alert for another country version of Google doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit tricky but feasible, you have to go to the alerts page of each Google local site your are interested.

For example, if you need to receive alerts for the game `Dota 2` in 3 different languages, like English, Italian and German you have to visit:

- [Google.com](http://www.google.com/alerts) alerts
- [Google.it](http://www.google.it/alerts) alerts
- [Google.de](http://www.google.de/alerts) alerts

and a new entry for `Dota 2` in each one of them.

Comment: I recon, `Dota 2` is the string you're looking for?

Answer (score 4):

This way works for me:

- Open Chrome in **incognito mode**
- Open google search .com .it .ro ... for place.
- Select your language in link under search box.
- Add `/alerts` on your browser bar. (Eg: `www.google.it/alerts`)
- And now you can create your new alert.

(Don't try to skip first and second step)

You can check on your Alerts manager, Export, and you will see language of each alert you've.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky at the moment. To get results in English you need to change your default language for Google Search to English. Go to [google.com](http://google.com), use the **Settings**->**Search settings** link in the top right corner, and change your interface language and search language to English. Then go to [google.com/alerts](http://google.com/alerts) and set up your alerts.

Comment: Thank you for answering Marcel, but I would like to configure multiple languages; let's say 2 would be enough Italian and English. For example I would like to get alert about "tf2" term every day from English search results pool and once a week from Italian results. Do you think is possible? If not maybe it would be a nice feature to add in the future.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Google forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/news/thread?tid=2137b5c384c76223&hl=en)

> For example, to get Spanish news alerts, first go to :
>   http://www.google.es
>
> Do your news search in that language, and then make your news alert from the news in that language's google news search engine and have it sent to your email.
>
> Create a new alert | Switch to text emails | Export alerts
>
> Chose csv and then chose to open it rather than save it. You can then open and look at it right away with Notepad or Word Pad.
>
> The file will contain the following information about each alert:
>   "Search terms","Type","How often","Volume","Language","Deliver to"

Answer (score 0):

Try entering this in the browser for English http://www.google.com/alerts?hl=en

Comment: What happened when you tried it?